# Как найти сумму чётных элементов одномерного массива?

Tags: c++, массивы

Пусть дан:одномерный массив, содержащий целые числа. Выполнить следующие
действия: Найти сумму четных элементов, попадающих в заданный интервал,
включая границы интервала. Ноль не учитывать. Если четных элементов
нет, вывести сообщение об этом.
 = 8  Массив = {1, 5, 9, 6, 2, 7, 4, 3}   Интервал =[2, 7]   Результат = 12
n =8  Массив  = {1, 5, 9, 5, 1, 7, 8, 3 } Интервал = [2, 7] Результат = таких элементов нет
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int* mas, n, sum;
    sum = 0;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    cin >> n;
    mas = new int[n];
    int k = 0;
    int b, c;
     cout << "b="; cin >> b; //ввод диапазона
     cout << "c="; cin >> c;
     if (b > c) swap(b, c);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "mas[" << i << "]= ";
        cin >> mas[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (mas[i] % 2 == 0) // проверка на четность
            sum += mas[i];
            k++;
    }
    if (!k) cout << "Таких элементов нет\n"; //k = 0
    else
    cout << "Сумма четных элементов массива равна " << sum;
    cin.get(); cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Почему при вот  этом {1, 5, 9, 5, 1, 7, 8, 3 } [2, 7] таких элементов нет;
У меня выводит количество элементов равно 8,а не то что таких элементов не существует.
Помогите пожалуйста исправить мой код.

Comment: А где вы проверяете вхождение в интервал?

Comment: У Вас `k++;` не является частью `if`

Comment: @vp_arth,у меня k++ в цикле for,а как должен выглядеть цикл for по вашему?

Comment: Повторю вопрос. Вот эти вот [2, 7]. Где вы их вводите и проверяете?

Comment: @vp_arth,я просто ввожу количество элементов а интервал не проверяю.cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    cin >> n;

Comment: На данный момент, я почти уверен, что это первый попавшийся код из гугла по запросу "сумма четных элементов"

Comment: "не проверяю", тогда чему вы удивляетесь? Даже если вы почините баг с k++, в вашем массиве есть чётный элемент 8

Comment: @vp_arth,хорошо а объясните не ведующему как проверять интервал?

Comment: Собственно, [я был прав](https://prog-cpp.ru/mas-sum/). Главный вопрос, на который вам нужно ответить в первую очередь: «Когда все задания/контрольные закончатся и вы получите свой диплом, как вы собираетесь применять знания, которых не удосужились получить?»

Comment: @vp_arth,я вас понял,но давайте всё же придём к верной программе.
cout << "b="; cin >> b; //ввод диапазона
     cout << "c="; cin >> c;
     if (b > c) swap(b, c);
Вот это диапазоны,что из остального у меня осталось не правильное?

Comment: Где в Вашем коде используются значения `b` и `c`?

Comment: @Igor,они используются только при ограничении интервала от 2 до 7.

Comment: Где в Вашем коде используются значения, обозначенные буковками `b` и `c`?

Comment: @Igor,вот тут: if (mas[i] % 2 == 0 && (mas[i] < b || mas[i] > c))  // проверка на четность
Вот подправил

Comment: Это что такое, и как это относится к коду в вопросе? Это не скомпилируется.

Comment: @Igor,я исправил строчку чуть выше.

Comment: `if (mas[i] % 2 == 0 && mas[i] >= b && mas[i] <= c && mas[i] != 0) {`

Comment: @Igor,оно работает,спасибо вам большое за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Сравните

```
if (mas[i] % 2 == 0) // проверка на четность
    sum += mas[i];
    k++;
```

и

```
if (mas[i] % 2 == 0) { // проверка на четность
    sum += mas[i];
    k++;
    }
```

Видите разницу? (и свою ошибку)